# Redux patterns 'set' action vs 'add'/'remove' actions

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am currently creating an application with redux. I had a question, regarding the structure of our actions.  I will distill it into an elementary example below.  We are using immutable JS, and our store is constructed from immutable objects.

We have an input element that adds or removes to a store when the user clicks on an item in an array.  There are two fundamental ways this can be organized.  For simplicity, let's assume that the store consists of a single map of names such that 'names = Map()'  where the map looks like this:

{
name1: true
name2: true
}

**Strategy 1**

Uses a single action: SET_SELECTED_NAMES

**Strategy 2**

Uses two actions: SELECT_NAME, UNSELECT_NAME.

From my understanding of redux/react and after refactoring the code from strategy 2 to strategy 1- at the behest of my team- I am getting the feeling of massive code smells from this refactor but having trouble articulating them.  It feels as if we are moving logic that should be from the store into the component to know what the 'next state' should be.

When the user clicks an item we need to look at the current state from within the component and to understand if that click is to remove an item or add it.  Then we are passing the new state directly onto the actions rather than utilizing the store/reducers to 'compute' it.  This has the ultimate effect of making the reducers extremely simple and complicating the logic within the component or at the very least making it less verbose.

Turning:

isSelecting ? this.props.selectName(name) : this.props.unselectName(name)

Into:

this.props.setSelectedNames(this.props.selectedNames.update(name, v => !v));

Answer (score 0):

In redux you are free to add your `business logic` in both the action creators and reducers, it really depends on your setup and organization.

Personally I prefer thin reducers and fat action creator.

Strategy number 1, for my understanding, it assumes a fat action creator, where you check some logic and after some computation it set a payload for the reducer to process.

In my opinion this could work just fine, and keep the reducers very simple and only responsible to just update the state.

Article of interest:
http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#structure-business-logic

PS:
You could also consider an action, which send dispatch other actions based on some logic, and so using a mixed approach (Strategy 1/2).

```
const setLocation = (id:number):ActionType => {
  // check some logic here, and dispatch the right set of actions
  return dispatch => {
        dispatch(getWeather(id))
        dispatch(getForecastDaily(id))
        dispatch(getForecastHourly(id))
      }
    }
```